# Сообщения между клиентами не выводятся пока не произойдёт отправка

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сокет, асинхронность, p2p

На socket в Python реализую обмен сообщениями между пользователям, но в процессе обмена из-за вечного цикла не происходит вывод сообщения и одного из клиентов, пока он не отправит сообщение

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
HOST_IP = input('Please, type IP of server')
HOST = HOST_IP,10000
username = input("Please type a username ").encode('UTF-8')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(HOST)
s.setblocking(0)

header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('UTF-8')
s.send(header+username)

def send_msg():
    try:
        while True:
            print('Please, write a message')
            msg = input().encode('UTF-8')
            if msg: #если на вход поступило сообщение, то кодируем его и отправляем
                msg_header = f"{len(msg):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode('UTF-8')
                s.send(msg_header+msg)
                print(msg_header, msg)
    except IOError as _ex:
        pass

def recv_msg():
        
        while True: #Если нам поступает сообщение, содержащее заголовок, то принимаем его, показываем само сообщение и username того, кто отправил
            user_header =s.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            if not len(user_header):
                sys.exit()
            user_lenght = int(user_header.decode('UTF-8').strip())
            username = s.recv(user_lenght)

            msg_header = s.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            msg_length = int(msg_header.decode('UTF-8').strip())

            data = s.recv(msg_length).decode('UTF-8')
            print(f"New message from {username.decode('UTF-8')} - {data}")
```

Comment: это не из-за "вечного цикла", а потому, что вы сами так запрограммировали - ваш код ждет пользовательский input, который должен завершиться нажатием клавиши Enter. Вы какую логику закладывали в свое творение?